# How to implement a material design circular progress bar in android

Tags: android, material-design, android-progressbar

I want to make a material design circular progress bar like the one in Inbox by Gmail android app. How do I achieve this (in pre-lollipop devices)?

Am trying to achieve a similar effect like this.
[Inbox by Gmail material design circular progress bar](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B2WfHQxy1J_Ob29NNlpkbFJjaWc/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: https://github.com/passsy/android-HoloCircularProgressBar

Comment: help full link for u https://github.com/Sefford/CircularProgressDrawable

Comment: Try to use the xposed module smooth system progress bars by Mohammed AG as suggested by [Prajwal](http://stackoverflow.com/users/4672835/prajwal-mohan-praju).

Comment: @Zapnologica  Their example only works for android lollipop devices, the loading spinners are built into lollipop, but i was looking or ways to port it back to lower android versions

Comment: @cozeJ4 I was hoping for support library to provide such things.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Update

As of 2019 this can be easily achieved using `ProgressIndicator`, in **Material Components library**, used with the `Widget.MaterialComponents.ProgressIndicator.Circular.Indeterminate` style.

For more details please check
[Gabriele Mariotti's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62237062/3355634) answer below.

Old implementation

Here is an awesome implementation of the material design circular intermediate progress bar https://gist.github.com/castorflex/4e46a9dc2c3a4245a28e. The implementation only lacks the ability add various colors like in inbox by android app but this does a pretty great job.

Answer (score 50):

```
<ProgressBar
android:id="@+id/loading_spinner"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:indeterminateTintMode="src_atop"
android:indeterminateTint="@color/your_customized_color"
android:layout_gravity="center" />
```

The effect looks like this:

[image: img]

Comment: This wont work on pre-Lollipop devices. Pre Lollipop devices use a different spinning drawable

Answer (score 26):

Nice implementation for material design circular progress bar (from [rahatarmanahmed/CircularProgressView](https://github.com/rahatarmanahmed/CircularProgressView)),

```
<com.github.rahatarmanahmed.cpv.CircularProgressView
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/progress_view"
    android:layout_width="40dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    app:cpv_indeterminate="true"/>
```

[image]

Comment: Hi Fahim, what do you mean by Native progressBar ? Is that from the Android platfrom ?
I want to implement the same kind of dialog and better if it is available from android itself or from any support library.

Comment: @cgr Native ProgressBar is a progress bar implemented with Android SDK. If you run this app on two devices w/ different Android flavor (e.g.: Jelly Beans and Lollipop) you'll see different progress bar. Try it yourself.

Comment: Super easy, thanks. What's the best way to add an opaque background color? Like if I wanted to do a gmail type of indicator with black arcing circle upon a bigger, white background circle?

Answer (score 23):

I've backported the three Material Design progress drawables to Android 4.0, which can be used as a drop-in replacement for regular `ProgressBar`, with exactly the same appearance.

These drawables also backported the tinting APIs (and RTL support), and uses `?colorControlActivated` as the default tint. A `MaterialProgressBar` widget which extends `ProgressBar` has also been introduced for convenience.

[DreaminginCodeZH/MaterialProgressBar](https://github.com/DreaminginCodeZH/MaterialProgressBar)

This project has also been adopted by [afollestad/material-dialogs](https://github.com/afollestad/material-dialogs/releases/tag/0.8.1.0) for progress dialog.

On Android 4.4.4:

[image: Android 4.4.4]

On Android 5.1.1:

[image: Android 5.1.1]

Comment: Thank you for all your efforts! Great library! Keep it going!

Comment: Very elegant solution, in my opinion the best one

Comment: Thanks for the library! Is there a way to change the color of the spinner?

Comment: @Roymunson Check out the README and the paragraph about app:mpb_progressTint etc

Answer (score 20):

With the **Material Components library** you can use the **`CircularProgressIndicator`**:

Something like:

```
<com.google.android.material.progressindicator.CircularProgressIndicator
      android:indeterminate="true"          
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      app:indicatorColor="@array/progress_colors"
      app:indicatorSize="xxdp"
      app:indeterminateAnimationType="contiguous"/>
```

where `array/progress_colors` is an array with the colors:

```
  <integer-array name="progress_colors">
    <item>@color/yellow_500</item>
    <item>@color/blue_700</item>
    <item>@color/red_500</item>
  </integer-array>
```

[image]

**Note:** it requires at least the version `1.3.0`

Comment: What is the support fo this progress bar, is it working on PreLolipop?

Comment: @StoychoAndreev currently the minSdk = 14

Comment: Tnx for your code. but this class does not have attributes like "circularRadius" and "growMode". if it is existed, correct me.

Comment: @nIMaaZx thanks for feedback. They was replaced by `app:indicatorSize="xxdp"`
and `app:showAnimationBehavior`.

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti Thanks again for editing. I wanted to suggest editing but it did not permit to edit the answer.

Comment: where to put that array ?

Comment: @Web. Check this link: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/more-resources#IntegerArray

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti Sir Can i Put ?attr/colorPrimary in <integer-array>? I m doing something like this " <resources>
    <integer-array name="progress_colors">
        <item>?attr/nova_teal </item>
        <item>?attr/nova_grey_light</item>
        <item>?attr/black</item>
    </integer-array>
</resources>" but it doesn't show any color. Am  i doing something wrong?

Answer (score 9):

In addition to **cozeJ4's** answer, here's [updated version of that gist](https://gist.github.com/dmide/7506c7d9614eed90805d)

Original one lacked imports and contained some errors. This one is ready to use.

Comment: would you explain how can we use this?

Comment: copy these classes, change packages to your project's package and use MaterialProgressBar as a view in your layout, that's all

Comment: but i wanted to show this like when a async  task ended pro.bar aiso must be finish.

Comment: Wow! Thanks dude. saved me from lots of troubles using com.rey.material library.

Comment: Do you have linear version too?

Answer (score 6):

The platform uses a vector drawable, so you can't reuse it as in in older versions.
However, the support lib v4 contains a backport of this drawable : 
http://androidxref.com/5.1.0_r1/xref/frameworks/support/v4/java/android/support/v4/widget/MaterialProgressDrawable.java
It has a `@hide` annotation (it is here for the SwipeRefreshLayout), but nothing prevents you from copying this class in your codebase.

Comment: well, now that we have VectorDrawableCompat, you might just be able to reuse the same drawable

Answer (score 5):

Was looking for a way to do this using simple `xml`, but couldn't find any helpful answers, so came up with this.

This works on pre-lollipop versions too, and is pretty close to the material design progress bar. You just need to use this `drawable` as the `indeterminate drawable` in the `ProgressBar` layout.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><!--<layer-list>-->
<rotate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:fromDegrees="0"
    android:toDegrees="360">
    <layer-list>
        <item>
            <rotate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:fromDegrees="-90"
                android:toDegrees="-90">
                <shape
                    android:innerRadiusRatio="2.5"
                    android:shape="ring"
                    android:thickness="2dp"
                    android:useLevel="true"><!-- this line fixes the issue for lollipop api 21 -->

                    <gradient
                        android:angle="0"
                        android:endColor="#007DD6"
                        android:startColor="#007DD6"
                        android:type="sweep"
                        android:useLevel="false" />
                </shape>
            </rotate>
        </item>
        <item>
            <rotate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:fromDegrees="0"
                android:toDegrees="270">
                <shape
                    android:innerRadiusRatio="2.6"
                    android:shape="ring"
                    android:thickness="4dp"
                    android:useLevel="true"><!-- this line fixes the issue for lollipop api 21 -->
                    <gradient
                        android:angle="0"
                        android:centerColor="#FFF"
                        android:endColor="#FFF"
                        android:startColor="#FFF"
                        android:useLevel="false" />
                </shape>
            </rotate>
        </item>
    </layer-list>
</rotate>
```

set the above drawable in ProgressBar as follows:

```
  android:indeterminatedrawable="@drawable/above_drawable"
```

Comment: unknown attribute android:indeterminatedrawable

Comment: The animation is totally different.

Answer (score 0):

Loader with background.

Add to your layout:

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:id="@+id/loader"
    android:layout_width="35dp"
    android:layout_height="35dp"
    android:visibility="visible"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/background_loader"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:src="@drawable/background_loader"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent" />

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/spinner_loader"
        android:layout_width="31dp"
        android:layout_height="31dp"
        android:indeterminateTintMode="src_atop"
        android:indeterminateTint="@color/blue"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Then add the background_loader.xml file to res/drawable:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="oval">
    <solid android:color="#ffffff"/>
    <size android:width="35dp" android:height="35dp"/>
</shape>
```

Managing the visibility of the loader in the code:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private lateinit var loader: ConstraintLayout
    
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        
        loader = findViewById(R.id.loader)
        loader.visibility = View.VISIBLE
    }
}
```

Result:

[image]