# How do I use the loading spinner animation from Lollipop in an older version of Android?

Tags: android, android-progressbar

I'd like to display a consistent loading spinner animation across all versions of Android. Ideally, I'd like to use the loading spinner animation from Lollipop in older versions of Android. Is such a thing possible?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<com.github.rahatarmanahmed.cpv.CircularProgressView
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/progress_view"
    android:layout_width="40dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    app:cpv_indeterminate="true"/>
```

### [REFERENCE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26814798/how-to-implement-a-material-design-circular-progress-bar-in-android)