# Create custom Progressbar with color change at rotate in Android

Tags: android

I want to create custom Progress bar which color is change every time when Rotation finish...

**For example:**

- 1st roation - red color
- 2nd roatation - blue color
- 3rd roatation - green color

Comment: Are you looking for [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26814798/how-to-implement-a-material-design-circular-progress-bar-in-android) ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use readymade libs available to do so

[ProgressWheel](https://github.com/Todd-Davies/ProgressWheel),

[android-circular-progress-bar](https://github.com/chillerlabs/android-circular-progress-bar)

The best one [Android-ProgressViewsLib](https://android-arsenal.com/details/1/3186)

Answer (score 1):

There are so many library available on github you can use anyone.

1. [Android-RoundCornerProgressBar](https://github.com/castorflex/SmoothProgressBar)
2. [materialish-progress](https://github.com/pnikosis/materialish-progress)
3. [material](https://github.com/rey5137/material)
4. [ProgressWheel](https://github.com/Todd-Davies/ProgressWheel)

and just for the record you can find more [here](https://www.google.co.in) ;)